# What is the Vaex command for pd.isnull().sum()?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, vaex

Someone please give me a VAEX alternative for this code:

```
df_train = vaex.open('../input/ms-malware-hdf5/train.csv.hdf5')
total = df_train.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending = False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Vaex does not at this time support counting missing values on a dataframe level, only on an expression (column) level. So you will have to do a bit of work yourself.

Consider the following example:

```py
import vaex
import vaex.ml
import pandas as pd

df = vaex.ml.datasets.load_titanic()

count_na = []  # to count the missing value per column
for col in df.column_names:
    count_na.append(df[col].isna().sum().item())

s = pd.Series(data=count_na, index=df.column_names).sort_values(ascending=True)
```

If you think this is something you might need to use often, it might be worth it to create your own dataframe method following [this example](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#Adding-DataFrame-accessors).